# Mean Euclidean distance in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors of sequences of size [batch_size, seq_length, 2]. I want to compute mean Euclidean distance between tensors. What is the elegant way to do this?

Comment: between which tensors? [batch_size, seq_length, 0] and [batch_size, seq_length, 1] ?

Comment: No. two tensors are of shape  [batch_size, seq_length, 2]. where 2 corresponds (x,y) coordinates. I want to compute distance between those two tensors

Comment: Ok, and you want a single number that represents the mean over the batch size or a batch size of distances? What should the output shape be?

Comment: A single number would be the output which is actually mean of distance of those points taken over all timesteps (seq_len) and all sample in that batch (batch_size)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given the two tensors `A` & `B` each with shape `[batch_size, seq_length, 2]`, you can compute the Euclidean distance (L2 norm) using [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm):

```
l2_norm = tf.norm(A-B, ord='euclidean')
```

Comment: How does it make sure that the third dimension is my (x.y) points? I mean do we need to specify axis?

Comment: When the axis parameter is not specified the norm is computed pointwise, that means that A & B are reshaped into a 1D long vector with shape [batch_size*seq_length * 2]. Thus every point in the general position (x,y) of A is compared with the same point (x,y) of B

Comment: Just an aside: avoid using tf.norm whenever possible, especially when you need to compute gradients. This is because `tf.sqrt` is numerically unstable near 0 and is prone to give NaNs. Use the squared distance if you can

Comment: Do you mean `tf.squared_difference(a,b)` without squared root?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm:

```
tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(
    input_tensor, axis=None, keepdims=False, name=None
)
```

see the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_euclidean_norm).